# Hash # tag for SEO and Mod Rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, seo

My objective is to use the hash # tag to help making web pages canonical. I've already implemented the canonical meta tag but our SEO expert says it will be even better with the # tag for pages which are not index by browsers, search engines that does not yet support the canonical meta tags etc.

My plan is to insert the hash tag in our public urls: 
`www.mysite.com?id=456` will become `www.mysite.com#?id=456`

I then plan to use Apaches mod_rewrite to replace #? with ? to render the URL usable for the web server.

- Question 1: How can this be done using mod_rewrite? Is it a simple
  operation?
- Question 2: Will this work as I intend it too?

I'm using #? and not just # to avoid conflicts with potential anchors in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use mod_rewrite to manipulate anything following a hash.

Anything after # is purely for client side processing and is never sent to the server as part of a request.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it then possible to replace the a # character with nothing to remove it, using mod_rewrite?